# Aggregate analytics data by day/next day logic

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wrote a server for mobile app analytics in which I have a sharded(**!Upd**) collection with events as follows:

```
{
  "event": "install",
  "userId": "a",
  "time": 2014-02-09,
  "data" : ...
},
{
  "event": "login",
  "userId": "a",
  "time": 2014-02-12,
  "data" : ...
},
{
  "event": "install",
  "userId": "b",
  "time": 2014-4-29,
  "data" : ...
},
{
  "event": "login",
  "userId": "b",
  "time": 2014-4-30,
  "data" : ...
}
...
```

I need to select users, who have the event `install` and not `login` in next day after the `install` event (in other words, I want to select Users who install the app, but do not login in next day). So the output for above data should be:

```
{
   "userId": "a",
   "data" : ...
}
```

How do carry out this task with aggregation framework or mapreduce? Or maybe another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here another solution with mapreduce and aggregation:

```
var mapFunction = function() {

                      if (this.event != 'install' && this.event != 'login'){
                        return;
                      }

                      var value = {data: this.data, count: 1};

                      if (this.event == 'install'){

                         var nextDay = new Date(this.date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

                         emit({userId:this.userId, nextDayAfterInstall:nextDay}, value );
                      } else
                      if (this.event == 'login'){
                          emit({userId:this.userId, nextDayAfterInstall:this.date}, value );
                      }


                   };


var reduceFunction = function(event, values) {

                        var value = { data: null, count: 1 };

                         for (var index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
                            value.count += values[index].count;
                            value.data = values[index].data;
                         }

                         return value ;
                      };           

db.events.mapReduce(
                     mapFunction,
                     reduceFunction,
                     { out: "case1_mr_out" }
                   )         


var groupByUserId = {
    $group : 
    { 
        _id : { userId: "$_id.userId" },
        data : { $last: '$value.data' },
        count : { $max: '$value.count' }
    } 
}       

var filterWhereOnlyOne = {
    $match : {
        "count" : 1
    }
};            

db.case1_mr_out.aggregate([groupByUserId,filterWhereOnlyOne])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is  a bit tricky one :-)
You can do it with aggregation, if time is just a date field (without time data),
then 
having collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57694365ef9176ec54960a66"),
    "event" : "install",
    "userId" : "a",
    "time" : ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00.000Z")
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57694365ef9176ec54960a67"),
    "event" : "login",
    "userId" : "a",
    "time" : ISODate("2014-12-02T00:00:00.000Z")
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57694365ef9176ec54960a68"),
    "event" : "install",
    "userId" : "b",
    "time" : ISODate("2014-04-29T00:00:00.000Z")
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57694365ef9176ec54960a69"),
    "event" : "login",
    "userId" : "b",
    "time" : ISODate("2014-04-30T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

we can use aggregate query:

```
var match = {
    $match : {
        "event" : "install"
    }
};

var projectNextDayDate = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        event : 1,
        userId : 1,
        time : 1,
        nextDay : {
            $add : ["$time", 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000]
        }

    }
}

var lookup = {
    $lookup : {
        from : "zella",
        localField : "nextDay",
        foreignField : "time",
        as : "mergedDocs"
    }
}

var nowMatchUsers = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        event : 1,
        userId : 1,
        time : 1,
        nextDay : 1,
        mergedDocs : {
            $filter : {
                input : "mergedDocs",
                as : "m",
                cond : {

                    $eq : ["$$m.userId", "$userId"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var findEmptyArrays = {
    $match : {
        mergedDocs : []
    }
}
db.zella.aggregate([match, projectNextDayDate, lookup, findEmptyArrays])
```

with this output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57694365ef9176ec54960a66"),
    "event" : "install",
    "userId" : "a",
    "time" : ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "nextDay" : ISODate("2014-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "mergedDocs" : []
}
```

The assumption here is that time is a date `2014-09-02T00:00:00.000` 
the other way to merge collection is to use user ID, as a `$lookup` point, but then there will be more logic to filter result set and performance could be dropped.

Comment: Thanks, solution worked, but `lookup` not supports sharded collections, so now I try understand chridam solution, that seems bit more tricky :)

Comment: haha :-)  that info should be in the question :-), Christopher answer will work on sharded collection

Comment: Sorry, when i asked question, i I did not know about this limit.

Comment: no problem at all :-) we all are humans learning how to deal with mongo :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "event": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "time": 1,
            "data": 1,
            "dayAfter": {
                "$add": [ "$time", 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "event": { "$in": ["install", "login"] } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
            "eventsTimeLine": {
                "$push": {
                    "event": "$event",
                    "time": "$time",
                    "dayAfter": "$dayAfter"
                }
            },
            "data": { "$push": "$data" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$eventsTimeLine" },
    { "$sort": { "eventsTimeLine.event": 1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "dayAfterInstall": { "$first": "$eventsTimeLine.dayAfter" },
            "loginTime": { "$last": "$eventsTimeLine.time" },
            "data": { "$first": "$data" }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "isChurn": { "$ne": [ "$loginTime", "$dayAfterInstall" ] },
            "userId": "$_id", "data": 1, "_id": 0 
        } 
    },
    { "$match" : { "isChurn" : true } }
])
```